# shell script process fork

Tags: shell-script, shell, process, fork

I am doing some experiments to know how environment variables are inherited from parent process to child process by executing shell scripts in `zsh` and then use `pstree <username>` to see the inheritance tree.

I suppose that zsh do a fork to run a script. But the process name in the pstree is the script file name not `zsh`.

```
#parent.sh
#! /bin/zsh
export AMA=1
./childEcho.sh #call child
```

---

```
#childEcho.sh
#! /bin/zsh
echo ${AMA}
./subchild.sh #call sub_child
```

---

```
#subchild.sh
#! /bin/zsh
echo ${AMA}
sleep 5d #sleep so that pstree can see the process tree
```

---

Then `pstree` shows that

```
sshd───zsh───parent.sh───childEcho.sh───subchild.sh───sleep
```

Then I delete the hashbang header in the scripts, run again and then by `pstree`, I will get

```
sshd───zsh───sh───sh───sh───sleep
```

So the process is now sh instead of the script file name.

1. Why we have this different behavior?
2. How pstree determines the process name and draws the tree?
3. Something changed the process name at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A program can change it's own command line (as shown in `ps`'s CMD column, or `pstree`). That's what zsh is doing—it's changing its command name to the shell script, presumably to make it easier to tell what each zsh is doing when looking at `ps`.

For example (though I'm using bash, not zsh, but the same works in zsh—I tested):

```
$ perl -E '$0 = "I AM PERL"; sleep(60);' &
[1] 504
$ ps 504
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
  504 pts/22   S      0:00 I AM PERL
```

You can get the actual executable by `readlink /proc/PID/exe`, at least on Linux.